# Why is the content of the <head> tag no longer loading in Google Chrome?

Tags: theming

For some strange reason, the content of the `<head>` tag no longer loads in Google Chrome Inspector. The CSS files are still loaded.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be kpr. When this function is used head content load but will not show in the chrome inspector tool.

Answer (score 0):

That is for sure *not* a Drupal problem. I'd check the page source to see the head contents; if they appear there, maybe there is an unclosed tag.

Comment: Page view source does show all the contents. Just not showing them in the inspector tool.